# extracting previous word from string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with employee biographies.

One of the columns is named Biography.

Some entries describe how many years the employee has worked at the company.

An example:

"Gary has worked for us for 8 years"

I want to extract the number of years each employee has worked for the company.

I need an sql query that will identify for each entry the word "years", extract the previous word as an INT, and store this number in the same row as a new column.

Can somebody help explain how to do this for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Use substring to extract particular keyword from string... find the below example to use SUBSTRING.... SELECT 

SUBSTRING(YourField, CHARINDEX(Keyword,YourField)

Comment: There many other easy ways to get the same result... Here is the link below.   


https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-sql-server

Comment: Mysql is not designed for text analytics, so I would definitely not use mysql functions to get these results. R or python have tons of libraries for this purpose, use one of those and point them to your mysql database. For this particular use case, I would simple get the employee start date from the HR system and calculate the tenure from there.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` returns the substring from the given string before a specified number of occurrences of a delimiter.

**Syntax:**

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, delimeter, count)
```

- string: column_name or a constant string
- delimeter: string before which we are finding the prefix
- count: The number of times to search for the delimiter

Taking `tablename as test` and column name which we need to update as `new_column` and column containing string as `query_string`

```
UPDATE test SET new_column=(SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(query_string, 'years', 1)), ' ', -1 ) )
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(trim(substring_index(col, 'years', 1)), ' ', -1)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=efe62534bcca36853c24eaede1417181) is a db<>fiddle.